# render json error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
   def tag_autocomplete
        @tags = Tag.find_by_sql("SELECT tag_name as id,tag_name as label,tag_name as value FROM tags ")
        render :json => @tags.to_json
     end
```

render json not working I am getting the following error

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)):
    /app/controllers/tags_controller.rb:32:in `to_json'
```

I am using ruby 1.8.6 and rails 2.3.5

Thanks in Advance

Comment: How does your tag module look like?

Comment: Are you by any chance overriding `to_json` method in model `Tag`?

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps

```
format.json { render json: @tags }
```

**Edit**

It might be the sql statement or the class members naming.   Could you post your Tag class, please.

Try this.  If it works it means the class and variable names do not match the db columns.  You can fix that at the module\class to indicate the column name.

```
@tags = Tag.all
render :json => @tags
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried that one also but same error

Answer (score 0):

Actually, You do not need to_json.
render :json => @tags 
will be enough